# Ручное управление памятью в лиспе

Tags: lisp, unsafe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в лиспе работать с собственными структурами как в с++? Например вручную указать сколько памяти выделить для хранения и т.п. Гуглил, что можно делать как то через `FFI`, но ни одного примера не нашел, поэтому спрашиваю на данном форуме - можно ли управлять памятью программы и работать с указателями вручную?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы выбрали подходящий язык для вашей задачи?

Comment: @VladD Это Вы про C++? Статистика утверждает, что сложные программы на лиспе вдвое дешевле си-плюс-плюсных аналогов...

@34234 А нафига Вам это самое ручное управление? "Может ли трактор давать навоз?"

Comment: @alexlz: по статистике — да, но это лишь в среднем. Каждый язык хорош для своей задачи. Вот я и спрашиваю у ТС, не ошибся ли он с подбором языка к задаче. (Кстати, мы с вами ещё не знаем саму задачу.)

Comment: @VladD Если вас так интересует задача то это саморасширение и самооптимизация транслятора языка программирования при обнаружении новых способов решения задач или закономерностей, т.е. мне нужно метапрограммирование и работа с транслятором (компилятором или интерпретатором) в памяти.

Comment: @новичок34234: ну, если ваш транслятор может саморасширяться, почему бы ему не добавить в себя семантику указателей, выделения и освобождения памяти и тому подобного? эти операции практически напрямую отображаются в машинный код.

Comment: @VladDда не мой транслятор, а я ищу язык программирования с транслятором, который бы отвечал моим начальным требованиям. Вот и спрашиваю в лиспе такое возможно? Конечно можно на ассемблере с нуля вообще все сделать, но это слишком трудоёмко.